# Python interpeter uses previous version of numpy despite updated version being installed - how to fix?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, command-line, version-control, upgrade

When I run `pip freeze` in the command line, I see: `numpy==1.16.3`. I am trying to run `numpy.isin(...)` ([documented here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)), but I get the error

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isin'.

So I check the version of python being run in the python script as:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.__version__)
```

This outputs:

```
1.8.0rc1
```

And since the function was introduced in version 1.13.0, I need to figure out why the older version of numpy is being used instead of the up-to-date version. I usually upgrade with pip in the command line. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Which OS are you using? What do you see if you type `print(np.__file__)`?

Comment: `print(np.__file__)` outputs `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py`. I am using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

Comment: I cannot help much since I do not know much about Apple's product, but my guess would be that pip uses a different python interpreter and that you have 2 different versions of numpy installed somehow. Do you use virtualenv? An easy solution would be to use anaconda or miniconda.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody else has a similar problem, I followed the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDYL22QNiWk&) to familiarize myself with `pipvirtualenv`. I installed the updated version of `numpy` in the `pipvirtualenv`while in the same directory as my python script(s). While there, I entered the virtual env shell and then ran the command - it worked. I then used `exit` (as opposed to `deactivate`) to deactivate the shell, and tried the script while outside the shell - it worked again.